# Setting Mongo CLI result size

Tags: mongodb, command-line-interface

When querying something with find() in the MongoDB Commandline 10 results are returned and I can get the next 10 with the `it` command.

How do increase the returned amount?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the shell you can do the following:

```
 DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 25
```

That would set it to return 25 results instead.